# Python package of GAM with functions of tensor product and thin plate regression spline

Tags: python, h2o, gam, pygam

I'm searching for a python package of GAM model with the functions of tensor product and thin plate spline like mgcv in R. Specifically, like ti(a, b, bs = c('tp','tp')) by mgcv.
PyGAM has tensor product function te(), however it doesn't seem to have thin plate spline. Meanwhile H2O has functions for thin plate spline but doesn't seems to have functions for tensor product.
I'm a green hand of statistics and have no experiences in R programming. As I'm relatively familiar with python, I hope to use python to solve this problem. Is there any package that both of these two functions are available? Or is there any method to make a term like ti(a, b, bs = c('tp','tp')) in python?